# Athena/S3 Inventory query returns duplicate rows

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have created an inventory report (parquet). However when I query it using athena the result contains duplicate values. What could be causing this (I'm just querying the latest report generated).

[image]

I have the following views:

### Views

#### View (all_buckets_latest_report)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "all_buckets_latest_report" AS 
WITH
  tmp_table AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM
     "bucket1" t1
   WHERE (dt = (SELECT DISTINCT dt
FROM
  "bucket1" t1
ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 1
))
UNION    SELECT *
   FROM
     "bucket2" t2
   WHERE (dt = (SELECT DISTINCT dt
FROM
  "bucket2" t2
ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 1
))
) 
SELECT *
FROM
  tmp_table
```

#### View 2 (all_buckets_latest_report_clean_view)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "all_buckets_latest_report_clean_view" AS 
WITH
  deduplicated AS (
   SELECT
     t.*
   , array_join(regexp_extract_all(t.gen_file, '\d{6,}'), '') gen_hn
   , IF((gen_priority <= 2), array_join(regexp_extract_all(t.gen_file, '(?<=\-)([^.-]+)(?=\.)'), ''), IF(regexp_like(t.gen_file, 'test'), array_join(regexp_extract_all(t.gen_file, '(test)'), ''), 'unknown')) gen_type
   , IF((SPLIT(t.gen_file, '.')[1] <> t.gen_file), LOWER(SPLIT(t.gen_file, '.')[2]), null) gen_extension
   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY key ORDER BY key ASC) row_num
   FROM
     (
      SELECT DISTINCT
        *
      , (CASE WHEN (bucket = 'bucket1') THEN 1 WHEN (bucket = 'bucket2') THEN 2 ELSE null END) gen_priority
      , LOWER(split(key, '/')[cardinality(split(key, '/'))]) gen_file
      FROM
        "inventory"."all_buckets_latest_report"
   )  t
) 
SELECT
  bucket
, is_delete_marker
, storage_class
, e_tag
, size
, gen_file
, dt
, last_modified_date
, CONCAT('s3://', bucket, '/', key) s3_url
, key
FROM
  deduplicated
WHERE ((row_num = 1) AND (NOT (key LIKE '%/')))
```

**PS : The views queries were modified slightly for privacy.**

Checking the result of `all_buckets_latest_report` `all_buckets_latest_report_clean_view` individually.

### Expecting :

No duplicates in either.

### Results

`all_buckets_latest_report` : No duplicates
`all_buckets_latest_report_clean_view` : Duplicates

Comment: Your second query is really complex. Try simplifying the queries to track down the duplication. It also refers a lot to [gen_file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html) which I don't see in the documented list of inventory columns.

Comment: Thanks @IainSamuelMcLeanElder

gen_file is just part of the view that has the inventory. (So is any gen_whatever). It's created in this line `LOWER(split(key, '/')[cardinality(split(key, '/'))]) gen_file...`


I agree that it needs simplification. SQL isn't my strong suit. Any suggestions?